# How to make your meridians west-positive in basemap toolkit of matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using the basemap toolkit of matplotlib and I'm having trouble with making my meridians west-positive as opposed to east positive. Is this even possible with basemap?

In addition to this, I'm having trouble with the string formatting instructions given in the basemap API (https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html). The snippet of code I have below makes my meridians east-positive, but I'm not sure how to follow the string formatting instructions so that there is an "E" or a "W" after each tick increment. What am I doing wrong?

```
self.meridians = self.basemap_ax.drawmeridians(numpy.around(numpy.degrees(coord_lons)),
    labels=[1,0,0,1], labelstyle='+/-', fmt="%s", linewidth=0.5, color='gray', yoffset=5) % "E" #This will be either "E" or "W" depending on whether the meridians are east-positive or west-positive.
```

Here is a screen shot of what the meridians look like with this code snippet:
[image: screenshot]

Thank you! I appreciate the help.

Comment: Why can't you just work with east being positive and west being negative?

Comment: For 90 degrees east, what do you want the axis/tick label to *say*

Comment: In east-positive, everything should be in terms of east. The screenshot I attached is east-positive, that's why the increments go (left to right) from -180 to +180.  In west-positive, everything should be in terms of west. In this case, the increments should go (left to right) from +180 to -180.

Comment: For 90 degrees east, I want the tick label to say "+90 E."

Comment: The [labelstyle](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawmeridians) parameter only appears to allow a plus/minus *prefix* or an E/W *prefix*.  the format parameter will take a function as an argument - just write a function that returns the string you want.

Comment: I was hoping to use the fmt parameter to append an "E" or a "W" to the end of every tick increment. Is that not what it's supposed to be used for?

Comment: The fmt parameter will take a function as an argument - just write a function that returns the string you want.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out how to format the string. Now, is there a way to make my meridians west-positive as opposed to east-positive?

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer to the problem of string formatting. To append an "E" to the end of every tick increment, I simply did this:

```
self.meridians = self.basemap_ax.drawmeridians(numpy.around(numpy.degrees(coord_lons)),
    labels=[1,0,0,1], labelstyle='+/-', fmt='%g' + 'E', linewidth=0.5, color='gray', yoffset=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @wwii mentioned format parameter (fmt) can use formatting functions that you can write your own.

```
def fmt_lon(lon):
    str_lon = u'' + str(lon) + '$^\circ$D'
    return str_lon 

def fmt_lat(lat):
    str_lat = u'' + str(lat) + '$^\circ$K'
    return str_lat


parallels = m.drawparallels(np.arange(ll_lat+0.5, ur_lat, 2.5), labels=[1, 0, 0, 1], fmt=fmt_lat, fontsize=5, linewidth=0.25)

meridians = m.drawmeridians(np.arange(ll_lon, ur_lon, 2.5), labels=[0, 0, 0, 1], fmt=fmt_lon, fontsize=5, linewidth=0.25)
```

Simply call the function you need for the formatting you want. I needed to change the letters of (E, N) to Turkish counter parts (D, K). The above functions and calls worked.